# C++ double pointer to 2D vector gives out-of-range error

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, outofrangeexception

Apologies if this has already been answered, but I've read pretty extensively on this (I've been stuck here for several days) and I can't seem to find anything that works.

I'm trying to use a double pointer to access a 2D vector that is a data member of a class I have created. I have to use pointers for this because of the existing structure of a largish program that I have inherited. Anyway, the vector is initialized when the object is instantiated, like so:

```
CalcData::CalcData(int rows, int cols) : numRows(rows), numCols(cols), dims(2),
          data2D( vector<vector<MKL_Complex16>>( rows, vector<MKL_Complex16>(cols) ) )
```

(Yes, I realize I could use a template to avoid having to use type MKL_Complex16 over and over, but I'm a relative noob at C++ and I'm trying not to overcomplicate things.)
Anyway, the vector instantiates just fine, and using another member function I am able to get a double pointer that sees the first element of the vector:

```
MKL_Complex16** CalcData::Addr2D() {
    MKL_Complex16* helper2D = &data2D.at(0).at(0);
    return &helper2D;
}
```

Back in the calling function, I can see the first element of the array through the double pointer while debugging. The problem happens when trying to access an element that's out of the first row:

```
CalcData test2(72, 4);              // instantiate 2D vector object
MKL_Complex16** test2Addr = test2.Addr2D();    // get pointer to that vector
test2Addr[1][3].real = 56;          // write to an element
```

...in the debugger, this vector appears in the instantiated object as a 72x4 vector, as expected. But when I try to use the pointer to access it I get a segmentation fault. I *can* access, for example, test2Addr[1][0] by using test2Addr[0][4]. This tells me that for whatever reason my nicely-declared vector-of-vectors is being treated by the compiler as a 1D array. I tried solving this problem with an overloaded () operator but it turns out that this doesn't work with pointers (b/c joke's on me, I guess).

Basically, trying to use anything besides standard indexing [][] operators will make my life way more difficult. So, is there a way to force the compiler to recognize that my 2D array is a 2D array? Maybe by instantiating it differently? I'd prefer not to use push_back() if possible.

Comment: `return &helper2D` returns the address of a stack variable. This will fail when the stack is overwritten by another function call.

Comment: Haven't looked at all your post. But `return &helper2D;` return address of a local variable is definitely wrong.

Comment: Have you played around with vectors, before attempting vectors of vectors?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the scoping problem with the reference, that did in fact solve the access issue. I have a 1D vector member in the class that functions as expected (probably because I didn't need an intermediary var to return an address). I understand that this implementation may not be ideal, but it works. If anyone can suggest a link or method that can demonstrate how to implement a 2D wrapper for a 1D vector that preserves indexing via two [] operators, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to use a double pointer to access a 2D vector.

There's your problem. Visualise the data and you'll see what's wrong.

> This tells me that for whatever reason my nicely-declared vector-of-vectors is being treated by the compiler as a 1D array.

Because, by using this pointer, that's what you told it to expect.

> So, is there a way to force the compiler to recognize that my 2D array is a 2D array?

No, because it isn't.

Unfortunately people keep using and propagating misleading terms, and that's what's happened here: **there is no such thing as a 2D vector.**

You have a vector of vectors. Not one vector managing a 2D collection of `MKL_Complex16`s; a vector of vectors. Each of the elements in your outer vector, is another vector consisting of a pointer to the data and some other internals (such as a length). It is not efficient and it is not compatible with a `MKL_Complex16**`.

Worse, your `Addr2D` function merely returns a (dangling) pointer to a local variable (the `helper2D` object). You can't just keep adding more `&` until the compiler errors go away, to get the job done.

My advice for 2D data is always the same: make a class that wraps a simple `vector<MKL_Complex16>`, that contains *N×M* elements; have it wrap accesses too (e.g. *pos<sub>actual</sub> = pos<sub>x</sub> + pos<sub>y</sub> × width*), to simulate the two dimensions that you envisage. Then your storage really is just a massive, contiguous block of all the elements — and you can still conveniently index it in two-dimensions if you want to.

Comment: Changing the helper variable to a class member solved the access problem.
That being said, I can understand that there are some contiguity problems for vector-of-vectors, and a memory space is simply a succession of addresses and not a true 2D space, but it still seems to me that, literal or not, the idea of a 2D vector is an extremely useful fiction which is why most newcomers tend to latch on to it. I attempted a wrapper for 1D access, but the only method I could wrap my head around involved overloading the () operator, which failed as soon as pointer-level access was required.

Comment: I can conceptually understand a wraparound function, but my understanding of the details is still too muddy to implement it well. Bear in mind that:
- I am working with an existing codebase that likely can't change the access method withou a major overhaul and
- I am an electrical engineering student working on a fourth-year-spanning project who has been thrown into the deep end as far as usage of C++ is concerned. My deepest programming experience to this point is in the form of a one-term C class (not C++) that I took three years ago, and so there are bound to be major holes in my chops.

Comment: P.S. thanks for pointing out the scope issue, as it will at least allow me to move forward. If you can suggest a link with a good implementation for a 2D wrapper for 1D that preserves [][] operator access, that would be super helpful. I do understand the algorithm needed, I just wasted half a weekend trying and failing to implement it.

Comment: @ZachStamler: _"the idea of a 2D vector is an extremely useful fiction"_ Absolutely, but if you want one, you're going to have to create it yourself (this is effectively my suggestion from the final paragraph). _"the only method I could wrap my head around involved overloading the () operator"_ Yep _"which failed as soon as pointer-level access was required"_ It should be easy once you have a reference to an element

Comment: _"I am working with an existing codebase that likely can't change the access method withou a major overhaul "_ Then you need a major overhaul, because your current access method for these data is quite simply incorrect.

Comment: _"If you can suggest a link with a good implementation for a 2D wrapper for 1D that preserves [][] operator access"_ Hmm it would require a little proxy class but is ultimately not too hard. I'm sure I could Google something for you but instead I might as well just whip something up for you myself, when I get a min

Comment: Right where were we

Comment: Okay here's a very rough sketch which "works". It's not really a vector in the common C++ sense, because it has no iterable interface, and its `value_type` is indirect (a bit like `vector<bool>`), and it can't be resized. It allocates everything on construction. But you get the gist... http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31060f4687e11af2 Crucially, `&v[0][0]` will give you a `int*` which points to the entire data block if you need it